# If an order having multiple products, how can the shipment of each product be tracked in Magento 2?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2.2, shipment-tracking

For an Order there will be multiple products. It is not necessary that all the products will be received to the customer in a single day. So in such a situation how can the customer get to know their products tracking details. Can any one say relation of how these Order-Shipment-multiple products related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are asking for is called "Split Order". In Split Order functionality, an order with multiple items is split into multiple separate orders.

Each such order is then trackable individually.

There are many extensions available for split order functionality.

Below are some of the extension links:

https://store.webkul.com/Marketplace-Split-Order-for-Magento2.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/sunarc-magento2-splitorder.html

Comment: Thanks! So, but in Ship could you tell me what is purpose of adding multiple tracking ID?

Comment: If you are shipping multiple products through different sources or shipping carriers, then multiple tracking IDs are required.

Comment: so then again another question popped up. How is this multiple tracking related to these multiple products. I mean like how to identify to which product -which tracking id is mapped?

Comment: As I said in my answer: In Split Order functionality, an order with multiple items is split into multiple separate orders.

Comment: another question, like you said if going for split Order functionality.Then for each product will have different delivery charge right. So in that case customer's would be charged more when compared to that of single order. And if so then it is not the correct method going for split order.

Comment: It is totally up to the website owner, how he manages the shipment. I don't think that splitting order will charge more for customer if you manage shipping in right manner.